# Can I change which apps the dash displays for a keyword?

Tags: 12.10, unity-dash, webapps, gmail

I am using the web app for gmail which is working fine except that when I hit the dash and type `mail` all I get is Thunderbird. If I type `gmail` then the web app shows but not on the word `mail`.

My question is whether there's a way to manually add the gmail web app to appear when I type `mail` in the dash.

Comment: Not an answer but you may want to read Wendy's experience with the Dash here: [5 problems with Ubuntu 12.04 part 1: Unity Dash usability issues](http://www.linuxuser.co.uk/opinion/5-problems-with-ubuntu-12-04-part-1-unity-dash-usability-issues).

Comment: For the issue of `mail` not returning `gmail`, you may be interested in following this bug report: [Add sub-string matching to Dash search](https://bugs.launchpad.net/bugs/752259)